# How important are these weirdly written kanji?

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image: this]

I don't know what kind of font this is which is why I had so much trouble searching for an answer online.
Is this how Japanese people usually write Kanji? If so, how can I re-learn Kanjis with this font?

Comment: I'm rather very interested which site it is that shows kanji examples in cursive.

Comment: I found it in some forum, while trying to find out what kind of font that was, but I believe it was WaniKani with some special add-on, might be wrong though.

Comment: I see. FYI the font is [this](http://mtimti.sakura.ne.jp/font/post-770/). It's cursive in a very light touch that the structure is quite bleary (with some [ryakuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji)), so not for a beginner who wants to recognize kanji.

Comment: @brokenlaptop there is a user-created script for WaniKani that includes a bunch of different fonts and randomizes them for reviews. It's not sanctioned by WaniKani itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is 馬 in some handwritten font. It's moderately deformed, but it still retains the features of traditional [semi-cursive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-cursive_script) (行書) style. For example, the wavy line at the bottom represents four dots (灬), which is common in 行書. Any native speaker can read this easily, and a few may actually handwrite kanji like this, but beginners should not mimic the style of this font. I recommend using a more orthodox 行書 font if you want to learn 行書.

If this helps, roughly speaking, an English equivalent is a font like [this](https://www.dafont.com/milky-rainbow.font).